# How to distribute example files with Python and setup.py?

Tags: python, setuptools

I want to package an application that will be available on PyPi. Right now, you can close the repository and try out the functionality by pointing the script to one of the example configurations that are included as file in the repository.

However, Pip will install the application into Python's dist-packages directory which is not a very intuitive path for example files I would argue. Another option would be to create a dot folder in the home directory for the library, but I'm not sure if that's possible with setuptools.

What's the right way to distribute those example files?

Comment: You can include a separate command-line executable for the purpose of running examples. This will then be available to the user and they can run it by doing `myprogram --example1`?

Comment: @SimeonVisser Thanks for the quick reply. I have one executable that is made available to the user. One of the arguments is the path to a configuration file. It would be good to point to a real file for the examples to be consistent with that; that's part of the purpose of the examples.

Comment: That's possible, not sure how to make that easy because it'll indeed be installed somewhere. You can implement functionality to list all available examples (which you can bundle with the package) and then run them using a flag rather than a file path. You can then print the location of the file if people wish to inspect it or point them to available documentation?

Comment: @SimeonVisser I'd probably go with installing them into `~/.packagename/examples/`. In this case I would have to extend the install command somehow.